# 皆さんはどんな字を書いていますか？ / How do Japanese speakers write kana or kanji by hand?

Tags: kanji, orthography, kana, handwriting

## 日本語

この頃メタの方で[「手書きの文字をチェックしてください」という質問は受け付けるべきか](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1575/7810)という話題がありました。個人的には受け付けてもよいと考えているのですが、何人もの学習者がわけもわからず同じような質問を繰り返すのでは生産性がない、という意見があり、これはその通りだと思いました。学習者は教科書などから字の書き方を学ぶと思いますが、初学者用の教科書体といえども、毛筆の運筆を残していたり、規範的すぎて普段自然にみる文字とはかけ離れた部分があると思います。

[image] [image]

また、今まで漢字・仮名のような独特の書き方の文字に接してこなかった人にとっては、教科書を見るだけでは、何に気をつけて書けばいいかわからないこともあると思います。

そこで、学習者にまず日本で行われている普通の手書き文字はどんななのか一定の認識を示し、そのうえで疑問点を明確にして質問を投稿してもらえるように、日本語の手書き文字のサンプルを集めたいなと考えています。

- 自分はこういう字を書いている
- こういう字が一般的だと思う
- こういう書き方もアリだと思う

など、皆さんのご意見を募りたいと思います。よろしくお願いします。

（これはメインに置くべきかメタに置くべきか正直わかりません。移動すべきであればフラグを立ててください）

## English

Recently we have a topic on meta about [whether asking for checking handwriting is on-topic or not](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1575/7810). I personally think those questions are not necessary to be ruled out, though I have to agree with an opinion that it's not productive to allow many learners to submit similar questions totally cluelessly. Who'd learn to write Japanese would refer textbooks or other resources, on which might be printed 教科書体 characters for novice writers, which is still somehow detached from what we see in the outside world by being too prim, prescriptive, or carrying over brushstroke style.

[image] [image]

Moreover, those who haven't ever come into contact with peculiar writing systems such as kana and kanji would have difficulties grasping the gist however they stared at the textbook.

So I'd like to accumulate living samples of ordinary handwritten Japanese so that we can provide a certain reference point to possible questioners to help them know well what they're going to ask. Any suggestions e.g.:

- I write Japanese this way
- I think this is a typical example
- ... or an edge case

are appreciated.

Thank you for your cooperation!

(I'm not sure if this belongs on main or meta. If you think it should go meta, please flag it.)

Answer (score 4):

#### 手書きフォント

日本語は印刷用のフォントを作るのが大変だったり、カジュアルな場面で手書きが好まれることもあり、フリーフォントの多くが手書きのものです。読み書きの参考になりそうなものをいくつか紹介します。（画像はリンク先から仮名の一部を抜き出したものです）

- [ふい字](http://cute-freefont.flop.jp/huiji.html)
  わりとよくある字形だと思います。字画の細かい部分はかなり省略されます。
  [image]
- [隼文字](http://cute-freefont.flop.jp/serendipity_hayatomoji.html)
  かなり丁寧に書かないとこのような形にはなりません。それぞれの字の曲線の形に気をつけないといけません。上品な印象になります。
  [image]
- [ジンペン毛羽-R](http://cute-freefont.flop.jp/zinpenkeba.html)
  看板などでなるべく大きく見えるように書くとこのようになります。字をふくらませた時のバランスがわかります。
  [image]
- [ホリデイ-MDJP03](http://cute-freefont.flop.jp/mksd_holiday03.html)
  かなり雑に書いた字です。ひらがなもカタカナも同じような書き方になりますが、似た字の区別がどこにあるかが端的に表れると思います。
  [image]
- [みおフォント](http://cute-freefont.flop.jp/mio.html)
  くせが強い字で雑に書かれていて、普通の形と比べ変形が大きいものがありますが、このような形になることがわかれば読みにくくはないです。
  [image]